# Getting the correct control from an asp repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I'm working in ASP.NET and VB.NET right now. Here's how I display my view:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;
        <TABLE id="Table1" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <asp:repeater id="repVKM" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <br>
                            <input id="radioBtnID" type="radio" name="radVKM" value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(container.Dataitem, "BJBVKMID") %>'>
                            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "BJBVKM") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:repeater>
                </TD>
            </TR>
        </TABLE>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's how I fill the radiobuttons in the repeater:

```
Me.repVKM.DataSource = clsInschrijving2elijnManager.GetVoorkeurMateries(False)
Me.repVKM.DataBind()
```

And here's how I'm trying to see which radiobutton was checked:

```
Dim voorkeurMateries = repVKM.Items
Dim selectieVKM As String
For Each item As RepeaterItem In voorkeurMateries
    Dim rb As RadioButton
    rb = item.FindControl("radioBtnID")
    If rb.Checked Then
         selectieVKM = rb.Text
         Exit For
    End If
Next
```

It gives a "Nothing" error (like a null error) on the value for "rb" because it seems like he can't find the correct control? I don't know very much about VB.NET and ASP.NET so I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: You are using VB.NET not VB6 and that's `ASP.NET` not `ASP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, there is no `runat="server"` tag on the RadioButton so it can never be detected in code behind.

Second, you are looking for a RadioButton Control, while in the HTML you have a normal html radio.

So either add the runat=server to your existing RadioButton

```
<input id="radioBtnID" runat="server" type="radio" name="radVKM">
```

And change the code behind to

```
Dim radio As HtmlInputRadioButton = CType(item.FindControl("radioBtnID"),HtmlInputRadioButton)
```

Or make it a "real" aspnet control in the Repeater. Then the code in the loop is correct.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("radVKM") %>' />
```